# Lotus Domino restricted mail group creation

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to create a mail group in lotus domino using notes api. I want to apply a restriction on group that only group members can send email to group. I am able to create group but the people those are not members of group are also able to send email to group. I am using simple java code.

```
class MyGroup
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Session session=NotesFactory.createSession(host, username, password);
        Database directory=session.getDatabase(host, "names.nsf");
        Document doc=directory.createDocument();
        doc.appendItemValue("Form", "Group");
        doc.appendItemValue("ListName", "mymailgroup");
        doc.appendItemValue("ListOwner", "akash");
        doc.appendItemValue("LocalAdmin", "administrator");
        doc.appendItemValue("InternetAddress", "mymailgroup@abc.com");
        doc.appendItemValue("ListDescription", "My mail group");
        doc.appendItemValue("Members", "");
        Item memberList=doc.getFirstItem("Members");
        memberList.appendToTextList("member1@abc.com");
        memberList.appendToTextList("member2@abc.com");
        doc.appendItemValue("GroupType", "1")
        doc.replaceItemValue("$Readers", "mymailgroup");
        doc.save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the $Readers a readers item. Just add the following lines before your save:

```
Item readers = doc.replaceItemValue("$Readers", "mymailgroup");
readers.setReaders(true);
```

BUT: Like that NOBODY except the members see the group. You need to make the document visible to LocalDomainServers to make it addressable.

And: ListOwner and LocalAdmin are author- items. You need to use setAuthors(true) on them as well to make them functional.

Comment: That prevents picking the group from the directory, but does it prevent just typing the group name as an internet address and letting the router resolve the group members on the back end?

Comment: Thats what I thought in the past. But router is intelligent enough to send a delivery failure when addressing a group that you are not allowed to read!

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help...this has worked